# Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich FaceDetector does not return any Faces

Tags: android, arrays, api, face-detection

I've been messing around with the FaceDetector and Face classes in Android and can't seem to get the FaceDetector.findFaces method to populate the faces array with any Face objects in ICS.  I have tried running it in a 4.0 emulator and on my Galaxy Nexus running 4.0.2 and the array is never populated with any Face objects.  I tried running the same app on a 2.2 emulator and it works perfectly.  Did I miss something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html#findFaces%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.media.FaceDetector.Face%5B%5D%29), the Bitmap has to be in 565 format. To elaborate more, here's how you should load an image:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    Bitmap bmpFindFaces = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/to/image.jpg", opts);
```

I thought it was a bug too, because [someone reported it](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24686&q=findFaces&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars#makechanges). Maybe Google changed something in 4.0 and updated the documentation.

Comment: Not sure why you had 0 points, this was exactly the problem I was having. Thanks!